# How to update multiple objects in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to update multiple objects using IDs which i am passing in every objects that need to be updated but can't find any way to do it successfully. Here is my code

models.py

```
class EventTicket(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid_generate_v1mc, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

views.py

```
  class EventTicketView(APIView, PaginationHandlerMixin):
        permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
        def get_object(self, ticket_id):
            try:
                return EventTicket.objects.get(id=ticket_id)
            except EventTicket.DoesNotExist():
                raise status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            for each_ticket in request.data:

                ticket_id = self.get_object(each_ticket['ticket_id'])

                serializer = EventTicketSerializer(instance=ticket_id,data=request.data,partial=True)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    result = {
                        'message': "updated sucessfully"
                    }
                    return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                else:
                    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

````
class EventTicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventTicket
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

I have to send data like list of multiple objects :::
[
    {
    "ticket_id": "054665ea-4fde-11ea-94b2-9f415c43ba4c",    
    "name": "chris",
    "description":"The golden ticket for day only",

    },
    {   
    "ticket_id": "054656ea-4fde-11ea-94b2-9f415c43ba4c",
    "name": "daut",
    "description":"The premium ticket for day only",

    }
]
````

Comment: then what error you are getting?

Comment: Error is :: {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code will give you a proper understanding of updating multiple objects in single request.
For updating multiple objects in a single request it is best practice to use the PUT method instead of PATCH.
Here, the body data given is:

```
{
    "ids":[
        "5e41770d2e8fa013d1f034ec",
        "5e41772c2e8fa013d1f034ee",
        "5e4177702e8fa013d1f034f2",
        "5e453f302e8fa075aa18b277",
        "5e4a314f2e8fa070c5251a0a"
    ]
}
```

I'm updating the `enabled` attribute from `False` to `True` for given ids of DemoConfig model.
In the same way, you can update your data. As per your requirement, you can write `validate` methods to validate the body data.
Serializer is written to serialize the instance data for the response.

```py
class DemoAPI(APIView):

    def get_object(self, obj_id):
        try:
            return DemoConfig.objects.get(id=obj_id)
        except (DemoConfig.DoesNotExist, ValidationError):
            raise status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    
    def validate_ids(self, id_list):
        for id in id_list:
            try:
                DemoConfig.objects.get(id=id)
            except (DemoConfig.DoesNotExist, ValidationError):
                raise status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        return True

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_list = request.data['ids']
        self.validate_ids(id_list=id_list)
        instances = []
        for id in id_list:
            obj = self.get_object(obj_id=id)
            obj.enabled = True
            obj.save()
            instances.append(obj)
        serializer = DemoSerializer(instances, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serialiser for this view is:

```py
class DemoSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DemoConfig
        fields = '__all__'
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "5e41770d2e8fa013d1f034ec",
      "name": "CONFIG_1",
      "enabled": true,
      
    },
    {
      "id": "5e41772c2e8fa013d1f034ee",
      "name": "CONFIG_2",
      "enabled": true,
      
    },
    {
      "id": "5e4177702e8fa013d1f034f2",
      "name": "CONFIG_3",
      "enabled": true,
      
    },
    {
      "id": "5e453f302e8fa075aa18b277",
      "name": "CONFIG_4",
      "enabled": true,
      
    },
    {
      "id": "5e4a314f2e8fa070c5251a0a",
      "name": "CONFIG_5",
      "enabled": true,
      
    }
  ]
}
```

As per your code requirement, you need to use PUT method in the following way.

```py
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        ticket_ids = [i['ticket_id'] for i in data]
        self.validate_ids(ticket_ids)
        instances = []
        for temp_dict in data:
            ticket_id = temp_dict['ticket_id']
            name = temp_dict['name']
            description = temp_dict['description']
            obj = self.get_object(ticket_id)
            obj.name = name
            obj.description = description
            obj.save()
            instances.append(obj)
        serializer = DemoSerializer(instances, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I am sending BODY DATA like a list of objects which is [
    {
    "ticket_id": "054665ea-4fde-11ea-94b2-9f415c43ba4c",    
    "name": "chris",
    "description":"The golden ticket for day only",

    },
    {   
    "ticket_id": "054656ea-4fde-11ea-94b2-9f415c43ba4c",
    "name": "daut",
    "description":"The premium ticket for day only",

    }
] so using above approach is throwing this error :: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".  Also i have to pass name and description in DATA BODY to update the update , what modification can we do ?

Comment: in your case use ```        data = request.data
        ticket_ids = [i['ticket_id'] for i in data]
        self.validate_ids(ticket_ids)
        for temp_dict in data:
            ticket_id = temp_dict['ticket_id']
            name = temp_dict['name']
            description = temp_dict['description']
            obj = self.get_object(ticket_id)
```

Comment: @suresh check the edited solution as per the body data.

Comment: validation of data is up to you... but its standard practice to validate body data before updating instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot , working fine , i was doing some mistake in validation.

Comment: only problem with this it does not raise exception with bad request if one of the object id does not exist. it gives 500 internal server error. any idea? that is the error "exceptions must derive from BaseException"

Comment: in that case, instead of rasing bad request error in get_object() method, just return Response(data='xyz', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST).

Comment: Why is using put instead of patch is the best practice? Anybody know?